# Does creating, deleting same file has any side effect?

Tags: php

I am currently using this code which works fine

```
$messageFile="{$username}/new_messages.txt";

if( is_file($messageFile)){
    $results=@file_get_contents($messageFile);
  
    if(!empty($results) &&  unlink( $messageFile ) ){
        //manipulate
    }
}
```

I'm building a chat application in which messages are meant to be deleted upon delivery. `$messageFile` is only being accessed by two sets of people- The receiver and his/her friends.

Friends messages are appended to the file and the receiver checks for new messages ( through checking if `is_file()` or comparing last modified time--polling 3s) and once the messages are delivered, the file is deleted then keeps checking if the `$messageFile` has been created or modified again and has messages.

My question is based on your experience, has there been any side effect in creating, deleting frequently same file?

I don't consider using db since the flat file is only been accessed by a user and his/her friends and the messages are not meant to be stored forever and also querying and updating/deleting messages in mysqli database frequently (esp when there are lots of users) can be much work i guess.

Comment: What kind of side effects are you worried about? Wearing out the disk? No, that's not a problem. But if someone sends a new message at the same time as you're reading, you might delete the file before getting the message, so this is a poor design. Databases aren't really that hard to use.

Comment: @Barmar Could there be noticeable time in between reading and deleting the file where by new message could be lost since it wont be a large file?

Comment: No side effects, if you have 2 files. Else you can receive your own message and delete the file XD. For your case I'd suggest to use sessions, which behave pretty the same, creating and deleting files.. but much easier to manipulate and extend in your case.

Comment: @V.Volkov I will look into that. Thanks.